# gettype returning string when i pass Json_decode value of json_encoded array and stored in database

Tags: php, arrays, json

gettype returning string when i pass Json_decode value of json_encoded array and stored in database

ex:

```
 array(
        'SCHEDULED',
        'PERFORMED',
        'INPROGRESS',
        'DISCONTINUED',
        'ASSIGNED',
        'REPORTINPROGRESS',
        'REPORTED',
        'PATIENTARRIVED',
        'NOSHOW',
        'PRELIM',
        'REVERIFY'
    )
```

i have encoded this and stored in the database. when i am trying to retrieve the datatype of that value it giving me string.
please help out how to get its original type.

Comment: Yeah, so? A JSON string is a string. PHP doesn't have a JSON type.

Comment: Onces its encoded, its a string, you need to decode it back to its original data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try`json_decode($your_string,TRUE);`

You'll get an array again.

Comment: i have tried that. but, it is still returning string gettype(json_decode($string,TRUE));

Comment: then try first doing json_encode($string) then json_decode($string,TRUE);